# The "Possible Duplicate" link/auto-text should NOT be part of the question itself

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, exact-duplicates

When a question gets closed as a **possible duplicate**, [Community ♦](https://superuser.com/users/-1/community) edits the post to insert the "duplicate link":

> [image: 2][image: 3]
> [image: 4]

That's great! We should be directing users to the "original" question. The problem with this approach, however, is that this useful path between posts can be broken. Any user can go in and edit the post to edit or remove this link:

> [image: 5]

Or in the case of [this question](https://superuser.com/posts/452200/revisions), a suggested edit made **before** the question was closed and approved afterward, can indirectly remove this link.

The result being that you have a question that was closed as a "possible duplicate", but no mention of said duplicate post at all! This is not helpful.

---

Therefor, I propose that the "Possible Duplicate" link box NOT be inserted into question's body. It should be separate and handled similar to the `question-status` ("closed as ...") box.

> [image: 7]

(Thanks to [@soandos](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5464519#5464519) and [@Paul](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5466388#5466388) for the idea.)

Comment: there's a auto redirect for anon users to the dupe question.

Comment: @Sathya Do "closed as duplicate" questions get deleted after a certain age?

Comment: I fixed the question in question but this should probably be looked at.

Comment: @iglvzx not unless a question is migrated, or voted to delete.

Comment: On the pro side, it allows users to add additional links to questions with additional answers. It's also the only way question "originals" are exposed to the Data.SE API, so that would need to be changed as well.

Comment: @Sathya There's an auto-redirect? I don't get one when loading it in an incognito window.

Comment: @slhck [Automatically redirect anonymous user from unanswered duplicate question to corresponding answered version](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125220) indicates there is a redirect for unanswered dupes - not sure if it's active on questions with _no_ answers